# Removing rows based on intervals for a value?

Tags: r, subset

```
df = read.table(sep="",
            header=T, 
            text="Name    Age    Rate
                  Aira     23     90
                  Ben      32     98
                  Cat      27     95")
```

I would like to write a code that removes all age column observations between 25 to 30. So the outcome would result in the bottom row with the age 27 being removed:

```
df = read.table(sep="",
            header=T, 
            text="Name    Age    Rate
                  Aira     23     90
                  Ben      32     98")
```

I've tried to write it like this, but it quite doesn't like that I use two logics:

```
df <- df[!(25<df$Age<30),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subset`

```
> subset(df, Age<25 | Age>30)
  Name Age Rate
1 Aira  23   90
2  Ben  32   98
```

Using your original attemp

```
 > df[df$Age<25 | df$Age>30, ] 
    Name Age Rate
 1 Aira  23   90
 2  Ben  32   98
```

EDIT:

If you want to select values between 25 and 30

```
> subset(df, Age>=25 & Age<=30) # Option1
  Name Age Rate
3  Cat  27   95

> df[df$Age>=25 & df$Age<=30,] # Option2
  Name Age Rate
3  Cat  27   95

> df[!c(df$Age<25 | df$Age>30), ] # Option3
  Name Age Rate
3  Cat  27   95
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about doing the reverse then? df![df$Age<25 | df$Age>30, ] doesn't seem to quite work. Reverse, as in only the row with the age 27 gets retrieved.

Comment: @WoeIs see my edit. You can do `df[!c(df$Age<25 | df$Age>30), ]
`

Comment: Thank you so much!